# Unterschied zwischen „Fassen“ und „Glauben“

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

Ich würde gerne wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen *Fassen* und *Glauben* ist. Sind die Wörter austauschbar?

Ich konnte nicht viele Beispiele dafür finden.

I ask this question, because the translation for both in English is *believe*.

Comment: Diese Begriffe sind komplett orthogonal, und nicht austauschbar.

Comment: Ich verstehe aber, in Englisch die Beide meinen "Believe". Deswegen ich frage das.

Comment: In german [only a very specific context](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/fassen) of _fassen_ has the same meaning as _glauben_ (and it's unusual also)

Comment: Ah.. Ach so.. Ich denke, das ist ähnlich wie "Ich komme nicht dazu" --> "I cannot do it". The individual words are of different meaning but an expression as a combined means something different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The literal translation of *to believe* into German is *glauben*.

The literal meaning of *fassen* is *to grab*.

In a figurative meaning, *fassen* can mean *to get*, in some sense of *to understand*, *to accept*. And in that sense *fassen* can have the meaning *to believe*. It is only used in negated phrases:

So

> Ich fasse es nicht!

can mean

> I cannot believe it!

or

> It is unbelievable!

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I've understood this and updated about the same in ^ comments.

Answer (score 4):

Meiner Meinung nach sind diese Ausdrücke nicht austauschbar. In dem Fall von „to believe“ mag das vielleicht auf den ersten Blick so erscheinen, ist jedoch bei genauerem Hinsehen durchaus unterschiedlich:

- Wenn du etwas nicht *glaubst*, heißt das, dass du nicht genügend Vertrauen in die Situation/Person/Information besitzt, um dem Sachverhalt Glauben zu schenken.
- Wenn du etwas nicht *fassen* kannst, heißt es, dass du den Zustand/die Situation/Information eigentlich für nicht möglich hältst.

Ansonsten gilt:

- *glauben* → to believe
- *fassen* → to grab, to reach